# Save object states in .data or attr - Performance vs CSS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, performance, html

In response to my [answer yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9777624/1219121) about rotating an Image, [Jamund](https://stackoverflow.com/users/496735/jamund-ferguson) told me to use `.data()` instead of `.attr()`

First I thought that he is right, **but then I thought about a bigger context**... Is it always better to use `.data()` instead of `.attr()`? I looked in some other posts like [what-is-better-data-or-attr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4609071/what-is-better-data-or-attr) or [jquery-data-vs-attrdata](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9444679/jquery-data-vs-attrdata)

The answers were not satisfactory for me...

So I moved on and [edited the example](http://jsfiddle.net/vYB5r/4/) by **adding CSS.** I thought it might be useful to make a different Style on each image if it rotates. My style was the following:

```
.rp[data-rotate="0"] {
    border:10px solid #FF0000;
}
.rp[data-rotate="90"] {
    border:10px solid #00FF00;
}
.rp[data-rotate="180"] {
    border:10px solid #0000FF;
}
.rp[data-rotate="270"] {
    border:10px solid #00FF00;
}
```

Because design and coding are often separated, it could be a nice feature to handle this in CSS instead of adding this functionality into JavaScript. Also in my case the `data-rotate` is like a **special state** which the **image currently has**. So in my opinion it make sense to represent it within the DOM.

I also thought this could be a case where it is much better to save with `.attr()` then with `.data()`. *Never mentioned before in one of the posts I read.*

**But then i thought about performance.** Which function is **faster**? I built my own test following:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>test</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function runfirst(dobj,dname){
  console.log("runfirst "+dname);
  console.time(dname+"-attr");
  for(i=0;i<10000;i++){
    dobj.attr("data-test","a"+i);
  }
  console.timeEnd(dname+"-attr");
  console.time(dname+"-data");
  for(i=0;i<10000;i++){
    dobj.data("data-test","a"+i);
  }
  console.timeEnd(dname+"-data");
}
function runlast(dobj,dname){
  console.log("runlast "+dname);
  console.time(dname+"-data");
  for(i=0;i<10000;i++){
    dobj.data("data-test","a"+i);
  }
  console.timeEnd(dname+"-data");
  console.time(dname+"-attr");
  for(i=0;i<10000;i++){
    dobj.attr("data-test","a"+i);
  }
  console.timeEnd(dname+"-attr");  
}
$().ready(function() {
  runfirst($("#rp4"),"#rp4");
  runfirst($("#rp3"),"#rp3");
  runlast($("#rp2"),"#rp2");
  runlast($("#rp1"),"#rp1");
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="rp1">Testdiv 1</div>
    <div id="rp2" data-test="1">Testdiv 2</div>
    <div id="rp3">Testdiv 3</div>
    <div id="rp4" data-test="1">Testdiv 4</div>
</body>
</html>
```

It should also show if there is a difference with a predefined `data-test` or not.

One result was this:

```
runfirst #rp4
#rp4-attr: 515ms
#rp4-data: 268ms
runfirst #rp3
#rp3-attr: 505ms
#rp3-data: 264ms
runlast #rp2
#rp2-data: 260ms
#rp2-attr: 521ms
runlast #rp1
#rp1-data: 284ms
#rp1-attr: 525ms
```

So the `.attr()` function did always need more time than the `.data()` function. This is an argument for `.data()` I thought. Because performance is always an argument!

Then I wanted to post my results here with some questions, and in the act of writing I compared with the questions Stack Overflow showed me (similar titles)

And true enough, there was one [interesting post about performance](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3476497/1219121)

I read it and run their example. And now I am confused! **This test showed that `.data()` is slower then `.attr()` !?!! Why is that so?**

First I thought it is because of a different jQuery library so I edited it and [saved the new one](http://jsbin.com/uyuwoc/3/). But the result wasn't changing...

So now my questions to you:

- Why are there some differences in the performance in these two examples?
- Would you prefer to use data- HTML5 attributes instead of data, if it represents a state? Although it wouldn't be needed at the time of coding? Why - Why not?

Now depending on the performance:

- Would performance be an argument for you using `.attr()` instead of data, if it shows that `.attr()` is better? Although data is meant to be used for `.data()`?

**UPDATE 1:**
I did see that without overhead `.data()` is much faster. Misinterpreted the data :)  But I'm more interested in my second question. :)

> Would you prefer to use data- HTML5 attributes instead of data, if it
>   represents a state? Although it wouldn't be needed at the time of
>   coding? Why - Why not?

Are there some other reasons you can think of, to use `.attr()` and not `.data()`? e.g. interoperability? because `.data()` is jquery style and HTML Attributes can be read by all...

**UPDATE 2:**

As we see from [T.J Crowder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/157247/t-j-crowder)'s [speed test](http://jsperf.com/jquery-setting-attr-vs-data) in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9783831/1219121) `attr` is much faster then `data`! which is again confusing me :) But please! Performance is an argument, but not the highest! So give answers to my other questions please too!

**UPDATE 3:**

My test seems to be false because of the [fire-bug](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/firebug/) I used while testing! The same file in chrome listed `attr` faster and a second test on [jsperf](http://jsperf.com/jquery-attr-vs-data1) also says `attr` is faster

Comment: _"Would performance be an argument for you using .attr() instead of data, if it shows that .attr() is better?"_ **Yes... What else can be an argument?!**

Comment: Others could be: Better adjustable, beutifuler code, better editable, better understandable, etc... e.g. OOP Programming has less performance than procedural, but it is often better :)

Comment: *"Because performance is always an argument!"* Not in 2012. Let's look at your `runfirst #rp4` results: 10k iterations of `attr` took 515ms; 10k iterations of `data` took 268ms. That's 51.5 usec (*microseconds*, **millionths** of a second) each vs. 26.8 usec each. So you're wondering whether to use `data` if it saves you 24.7 usec. Humans perceive things on the order of tenths of seconds. So for it to matter, you have to do this op roughly 4,000 times in a tight loop for a human to notice the difference. That's just not even close to worth worrying about, even in a mousemove handler. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder i agree with you as you can see to the response of gdoron. I did mean that performance is an argument, but not always the highest :)

Comment: @Neysor: Ah, quite! *An* argument. Good distinction.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This performance part of the question *screams* of premature optimization; see below. *(Lest you get the wrong idea: I too am frequently guilty of wondering about the same sort of premature optimization question.)*

But getting performance out of the way (other points addressed below the graph): As far as I can see, `attr` is faster than `data` in jQuery 1.7.1: http://jsperf.com/jquery-setting-attr-vs-data This surprises me. Not that it's remotely likely to matter.

Gratuitous bar graph (longer lines = faster performance):

[image: Gratuitous bar graph from jsperf]

> Are there some other reasons you can think of, to use .attr() and not .data()?

At least a couple come to mind:

1. The advantage of `data` is that it doesn't have to write to the element every time; you only write to the actual element the first time, and from then on jQuery is just updating a value in a JavaScript object it maintains in a separate object cache (connected to the element via a key). *(I'm not sure why it's slower than `attr`; perhaps because of the indirection.)*
2. One thing I dislike about `data` is that it's not symmetrical: The first time you access `data` on an element, the data object is seeded with `data-*` attributes from the element; but from there on out, there is no connection between the two.

   Example ([live copy](http://jsbin.com/efazix) | [live source](http://jsbin.com/efazix/edit)):

   ```
   var target = $("#target");
   display("data('foo'): " + target.data("foo"));
   display("data-foo: " + target.attr("data-foo"));
   display("Setting data('foo')");
   target.data("foo", "updated data('foo')");
   display("data('foo'): " + target.data("foo"));
   display("data-foo: " + target.attr("data-foo"));
   display("Setting data-foo");
   target.attr("data-foo", "updated data-foo");
   display("data('foo'): " + target.data("foo"));
   display("data-foo: " + target.attr("data-foo"));
   ```

   Assuming the `#target` element starts out with `data-foo="bar"`, the output is:

   ```
   data('foo'): bar
   data-foo: bar
   Setting data('foo')
   data('foo'): updated data('foo')
   data-foo: bar
   Setting data-foo
   data('foo'): updated data('foo')
   data-foo: updated data-foo
   ```

   That can be confusing and surprising. The way you have to think about it is that the `data-*` attributes are default values only. I just don't like how they're so dependent on whether you've called `data` before or not; unless you *never* write to the `data-*` attribute directly, you can't be sure what value `data` will get (the original from the markup, or a value you updated later before you called `data`). It seems a bit chaotic to me, but if you set yourself rules (never write to `data-*` attributes directly and only ever use `data`, for instance), you can avoid the chaos.
3. When you use `attr`, you can only store strings. When you use `data`, you can store any JavaScript value or object reference.

---

> Because performance is always an argument!

Not in 2012. :-) Or at least, it's a lot lower down the list relative to other arguments than it used to be absent a specific, demonstrable performance problem.

Let's look at your `runfirst #rp4` results: 10k iterations of `attr` took 515ms; 10k iterations of `data` took 268ms. That's 51.5 usec (*microseconds*, **millionths** of a second) each vs. 26.8 usec each. So you're wondering whether to use `data` if it saves you 24.7 usec per operation. Humans perceive things on the order of tenths of seconds. So for it to matter, you have to do this op roughly 4,000 times in a tight loop for a human to notice the difference. That's just not even close to worth worrying about, even in a `mousemove` handler.

If you're into that kind of territory (4,000/second in a tight loop), you'll probably want to avoid storing the information on the element at all.

Comment: thanks for that, i liked your comment below. But i edited my post, because i did to much focus on performance, but i was really more interessted in the other questions :)

Comment: I read it and thanks for your 2nd argument. i did not know that they are prefilled with `data-*`. 3rd argument is clear to me and often used :)

But because i really want to know it: Would you use `attr()` in similar cases like [i showed you](http://jsfiddle.net/vYB5r/4/) although it isn't used in the time of programming. Just because you got a feeling that the designer could need it sometimes? Or would you always use `.data()` and if the request comes you will change it...

Comment: @Neysor: For what it's worth, I don't think I've ever used `data` in a web site or web application; I think I've probably only used it for storing state in plug-ins (since the state is almost always element-specific), and the state in question hasn't been anything the designer would want. In your image rotation example, personally I'd lean toward `attr`, but I think it's a subjective thing.

Comment: @Neysor: OMG, I completely misread my own graph. `attr` seems to be *faster* than `data`. Well, it was early in my day. :-) Edited.

Comment: AT:T.J. Crowder: OMG! I see and did read it wrong too... why is that? it is dissent to my test... :)

Comment: @Neysor: I have no idea why your test shows `data` to be faster, I'm not getting that result anywhere. One unusual thing about your test is that you're using the `data-` prefix even when using `data`, but I can't imagine why that would make the slightest difference.

Answer (score 1):

Given that `.data()` is indeed slower than `.attr()` [on *most* browsers](http://jsperf.com/jquery-is-data-faster-than-attr-data), but the speed difference is not important in this question, one advantage of `data()` over `attr()` is that data will automatically coerce `data-` attributes to `numbers` or to `boolean` values if they match.

That means that

```
<div id="boolean" data-t="true" data-f="false">
```

will result in boolean runtime value of `true` & `false` when you run this:

```
console.log($('#boolean').data('t'));  // reports true (not a string)
console.log($('#boolean').data('f'));  // reports false (not a string)
```

and

```
<div id="number" data-n="123.456">
```

will result in a number runtime value of `123.456` when you run this:

```
console.log($('#number').data('n'));  // Reports 123.456 (not a string)
```

`attr` on the other hand only works with strings, but will convert value to strings for saving. It will not coerce values when you fetch them.

The choice between `attr` and `data` depends on the feature you need for a specific example:

- Where I inject `data-` settings from the server into pages, I tend to use `data()` to access them, if only because it is shorter code.
- If I need the data to be visible in the DOM, I will use `attr()` to save the values`.

Answer (score 0):

You may use jQuery.data. It's almost always the fastest. jQuery tries to optimize its function on every browsers, and maximize compability. So with new versions of jQuery, you may gain performance for this function.
[This 2nd test](http://jsbin.com/ekofa/2) gave me `jQuery.data` as the winner.

Comment: yes i see. But i did not make my point clear enough. Sorry! But i did mean that performance is an argument, but not the highest. Other reasons should be also compared. So what are you saying about my other questions? (see update1)