# jquery variable seems to never get set after the first click

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is probably simple but the answer alludes me at this time. I have a button that I have attached a data attribute to ('data-faqid')

clicking on links on the webpage changes this data then when I click that button I am trying to get the value like so

```
   $('#faqSaveBtn').click(function () {
        var aFAQID = $(this).data('faqid');
        saveAClassFaq(aFAQID, sf);
    });
```

My problem is this:

I click on the button once and the value seems fine.  I click on other buttons that should change this data attribute and they seem to work when looking at the dom but the second and any other click always returns the value of the first time I clicked the button.

EDIT:  I change the faqid with this bit of code - in other click events

```
$('#faqSaveBtn').attr('data-faqid', iFaqID);
```

Comment: don't use the same id on several elements... id's need to be unique

Comment: Show how you are changing the faqid

Comment: post your html and js code that changes the value of the data attribute.

Comment: use class instead `class="faqSaveBtn"`

Comment: yea. provide all the concerned code

Comment: @TimotheusTriebl - its the only button with that id on the page

Comment: @kenken - why would class matter over id

Comment: @TimotheusTriebl Where are the duplicate ID's here?

Comment: @braindice its matter if you are going to use the same name in several elements. but you said that its the only button that has that id. so how you trigger the other button?

Comment: Just a shot in the dark, but are you sure that the other times you set the data that you're overwriting and not just adding several data-faqid="" tags on the same element? Causing the 'get' to just return the first one found

Comment: Can you show the function `saveAClassFaq()`

Comment: Did you mention that "faqid" is a pretty bad ID in terms of http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homophone? :D iFaqID makes it even more hilarious :D

Comment: possible duplicate of [.prop() vs .attr()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `.attr()` to set the data property. There is a difference between attributes (those are only valid for the HTML source) and their resulting properties (properties will be parsed once from the HTML source)

In order to change them you'd have to use `.prop()` or rather (in case of data properties) `.data(name, value)` to set the property

```
$('#faqSaveBtn').data('faqid', iFaqID);
```

Comment: great answer - helps a lot

Comment: I did a test a while back and it turned out that `.attr` was quicker than using `.data` so I use `.attr` for all my data attributes.

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9783598/save-object-states-in-data-or-attr-performance-vs-css) question and answer.

Comment: @JamieBarker, unless you are doing 100s/1000s of attribute changes in a single go, the speed difference between data and attr is negligible, and if you are using that much data than it should probably be stored somewhere else besides the dom

Answer (score 1):

Okay I dont know why he deleted it or if someone else did but @newmediafreek posted this

```
$('#faqSaveBtn').data('faqid', iFaqID);
```

This seems to work but not sure exactly why.  Apparently '.attr' is not used anymore or depreciated? (who can keep up anymore?)

Comment: Yes, the usage of attr has changed quite a lot over time and with jquery 1.7 (afaik) they added .prop in order to reflect the difference between attributes and properties

Comment: In short `attr` gives static value and `prop` gives dynamic value

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are updating the element attribute, but then trying to use jQuery's internal `.data()`.

The solution is to update the value using `.data()` not `.attr()`.

```
$('#faqSaveBtn').data('faqid', iFaqID);
```

What happens is:

1. The first time the button is clicked, it has a data attribute, and `$(this).data('faqid')` returns that value. jQuery has now started managing the `faqid` in its internal data storage, it no longer looks at the element attribute for the value.
2. You update the attribute value using `attr('data-faqid', iFaqID)`. The attribute changes, but the jQuery internal data is not affected.
3. The second click comes, and `$(this).data('faqid')` returns the value stored in the jQuery internal data structure